# enviar una lista entre llamadas de una pagina webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Buenas, tengo en una pagina tres dataGridview, uno de los datagridviews (gridviewSeleccion) se llena en función a las selecciones que se hagan en los otros dos. Entonces, debo mantener en memoria los objetos que tiene ese gridview para que se vayan cargando con los nuevos objetos seleccionados.

La pregunta seria como mando entre llamadas esa lista de objetos. para que cuando refresque la página no pierda la selección anterior

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de transportar datos entre solicitudes de páginas, y varían en función de los requisitos de la aplicación *per se* (Cómo la cantidad de datos a trasferir, la relevancia de los datos en términos de seguridad y la carga que se desea destinar al cliente/servidor).

En tu caso, si los objetos que quieres preservar son una lista del tipo `String` y no conlleva muchos datos, puedes usar un [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx) para almacenarlo sobre el lado del cliente.

O si prefieres trabajarlo sobre el lado del servidor se puede utilizar un [`SessionState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx).

En su defecto, si buscas guardar todo un tipo `Object` que signifique una gran cantidad de datos es mejor integrar la aplicación web con una base de datos.

[Aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1hkazw7.aspx) tienes más información para que tomes la mejor elección. ¡Suerte!

Comment: la idea es mandar 2 o 3, (no serán mas) registros tipo fileTable de sql.